# How to Send Pingbacks for all Posts in WordPress?

Tags: php, plugin-development, posts, functions, pingbacks

I deleted all my pingbacks and wanted to generate them again.

I found a some code on WordPress's site, which showed the function `pingback($Content, $ID)`

It send pings to all links mentioned in content.

I tried to use it for of my 800 posts.

```
<?php
require_once( 'wp-config.php'); 
require_once( 'wp-load.php'); 

set_time_limit(3600);

$Creations = get_posts( array('numberposts' => -1, 'post_type'=> array('post','download' )));
foreach ( $Creations as $Creation) { 
    $content = $Creation->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    pingback($content, $Creation->ID);
}
?>
```

It works, but only for couple of posts. The code itself doesnt generate any errors...

But after pinging 6-7 posts it says error 500, presumably it took too long to execute.

As a result I can not send pings for my posts.

Suggest a better way, or help me improving this code to send pingbacks from all my posts.

Just so you know, I am using Bluhost Shared Hosting (not very powerful) and the formentioned code was in a file that I directly ran rather than hooking to init

Comment: Is this something you want to do only once? as a cron job? or manualy from time to time?

Comment: Once, just for the sake of generating, but would keep the code with me if needed in future obviously...